# How to check day of the week in PHP

Tags: php

I use this code to display a line between 08.00h and 18.00h;

```
<?php if( (date('H') >= 8) && (date('H') < 18) ) : ?>
```

But I only want to display this line from Monday till Friday.
What line do I need to use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is technically about PHP (not Magento), and so you should check the docs on working with dates in PHP:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
date('w') // 0-6, Sunday - Saturday, relative to today
```

Now in the **context of Magento**, where GMT is forced on the system, you can get accurate readings based on the current store timezone in templates using:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('w');
```

Magento offers a lot of date/time handling capabilities. Regarding your question, most are found in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Date.php` and `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php`.

So, to answer your question:

```
<?php $weekday = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('w'); ?>
<?php $hour    = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('G'); ?>
<?php if ($weekday >= 1 && $weekday <= 5 && $hour >= 8 && $hour < 18) : ?>
<?php // do stuff ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

We can get the current time using the `G` format. Be certain of your logic on the time, too, where 8th hour is inclusive but 18th hour is excluded according to your sample code.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks! But how do I also integrate the time? Because I only want to display this between 08.00h and 18.00h.

Comment: Use the `G` format in the same way to get the time. See my updated answer.

Comment: do you know how I can manage the time by using time from 08.30h until 17.30h? I tried to change 8 to 8.30, but that does not seem to work.

Comment: How to this in magento 2?