# comparing time of day

Tags: date

what is the best way to compare the date?  for example i'd like to compare the hour of the day and if the time of day is a certain number execute a certain path.  How best to do this?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/50087/231

Answer (score 1):

Use the core functions to determine the current hour:

```
$hour = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('G');
```

whereas G is:

> G:    24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros, 0 through 23

taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php